# Program hangs if both written to and read from file in same execution

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite

I would expect the following code to write the number 42 to a binary file and then read and print out the exact value. And it does that but then it will not exit, just stall as it would when waiting for user input. Here is code that does what I explained:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[]){

    char *filename = "test.db";
    int *my_int = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    *my_int = 42;

    // First we open file to write to it
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    fwrite(my_int, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fflush(file);
    free(file);

    // Then we want to read from it
    *my_int = -1;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    fread(my_int, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    free(file);

    printf("Read back %d\n", *my_int);

    return 0;
}
```

I know that I can simply open it with the `w+` flag but I am just curious to figure out why it just stalls..

Comment: `free(file);` - undefined behavior

Comment: Why do you use `calloc` to allocate `my_int` when you immediately overwrite the `0`s it places there? It could be more efficient to use `malloc()` if you're planning on initializing it yourself before you ever read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't `free` a file pointer, you `fclose` it. Calling `free()` on a file opened with `fopen` is undefined behavior.

I'm sure if you replace your `free(file)` lines with `fclose(file)`, your problem will be solved.

---

I also recommend that you not bother allocating memory for `my_int` with `calloc` if you're using it only within that function. It may be better to place that memory on the stack, i.e. `int my_int` instead of `int* my_int = calloc(sizeof(int))`. The latter requires you to call `free()` later in the program, whereas the former does not.

Comment: I've followed your suggestions and arrived at this [new and bug-free code](http://gist.github.com/multivac61/a8b77adf2f3284336b2f24f6dcd1a0e1). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [[ fclose ]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/) to close the file.

```
fclose(file);
```

Also, the reference says :

> All internal buffers associated with the stream are disassociated from
>   it and flushed:

So

```
fflush(file);
```

could be avoided here.

Use [[ free ]](http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/dynamic_memmory_allocation/free.aspx) to release the reserved memory for a pointer. In your case

```
free(my_int);
```

would make sense, if placed before `return`.